# Putting a method with arguments into a variable, in JavaScript

Tags: setinterval, clearinterval

Sometimes I have difficulty in understanding the logic behind JavaScript and this is one example of something I often see. Here is a simple function that will be passed to a timer:

```
function myCounter() {
   //do something...
}
```

You can just pass it like this:

`setInterval(myCounter, 1000)`;

But, often we need to have the means to stop it so we assign it to a variable:

```
var t = setInterval(myCounter, 1000);
```

This allows it to be cleared later like this:

```
clearInterval(t);
```

I use this all the time but it bothers me that I don't understand exactly what I am putting into the variable, and why `typeof t` returns a number. What exactly have I put in t? Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign an interval to a variable, you are actually assigning an ID. That ID is then used when you use `clearInterval` to select which timer to clear. The reason typeof returns a number, is because an ID is a number.

[Here is a detailed explanation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

MDN is a fantastic resource for this sort of thing, I highly recommend it

Comment: So it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Often is! Use MDN whenever you're curious. Accept the answer if you can as well, to help others.